# Errors Pushing to Heroku (node.js)

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

When I push a default express app to heroku I get the following error.  I've ensured I am up to date with heroku-toolbelt etc but it appears to be an error from the heroku side?  Has anyone seen this?  It pushes alright and works as expected but I suspect this could cause issues in the future.

```
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 404 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Node.js app detected

/app/slug-compiler/buildpacks/nodejs2/vendor/json/json:425
  return runInNewContext("(" + JSON.stringify(datum) + ")" + lookupCode);
         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:118
    at lookupDatum (/app/slug-compiler/buildpacks/nodejs2/vendor/json/json:425:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/slug-compiler/buildpacks/nodejs2/vendor/json/json:628:24)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:61:17)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:656:51)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)

/app/slug-compiler/buildpacks/nodejs2/vendor/json/json:425
  return runInNewContext("(" + JSON.stringify(datum) + ")" + lookupCode);
         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'npm' of undefined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:118
    at lookupDatum (/app/slug-compiler/buildpacks/nodejs2/vendor/json/json:425:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/slug-compiler/buildpacks/nodejs2/vendor/json/json:628:24)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:61:17)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:656:51)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.4.7
       Using npm version: 1.0.94
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm

       express@2.5.8 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/express
       connect@1.8.5 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect
       qs@0.4.2 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/express/node_modules/qs
       mime@1.2.4 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/express/node_modules/mime
       formidable@1.0.9 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable
       mkdirp@0.3.0 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/express/node_modules/mkdirp
       jade@0.20.3 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/jade
       commander@0.5.2 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/jade/node_modules/commander
       mkdirp@0.3.0 /tmp/build_1m5t2ah1oglfb/node_modules/jade/node_modules/mkdirp
       Dependencies installed
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compiled slug size is 3.1MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
```

Comment: Yes that looks to me too like it is Heroku's error. Report it to them? https://support.heroku.com/home

Comment: Need to check if this is still happening.  Will report back ASAP.

Comment: Heroku Issue apparently . problem resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a heroku issue and appears to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that it has something to do with parsing your `package.json`. Take a look at [Specifying a version of Node.js/npm](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions). Is everything [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)?

My guess is that this `evalmachine` is evaluating your `package.json` in a sandbox environment (see [`vm.runInNewContext`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html#vm.runInNewContext)), and `lookupCode` is some way of, first, checking `engines.node`, then `engines.npm`. Are both of these accessible? If this is the truth, then shame on Heroku's Devs for not expecting this error and accounting for it with some useful message. They're usually good about such things.

Comment: Nothing wrong with my stuff - it's boilerplate and works on other environments.  Need to check if this is still happening shortly.